# Publish JPEG Image from Drive

Tags: ros, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I have this python code that is able to save an image on my hardrive in JPEG format. The question I want to ask if any of you guys know how to publish this image as a sensor_msg/image in ROS.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50531/publish-jpeg-image-from-drive/) by [ROS_NOOB_CYBORG](https://answers.ros.org/users/3275/ros_noob_cyborg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out this tutorial: [Writing a simple image publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages#Writing_a_Simple_Image_Publisher).

It provides an example of a minimal ros node which reads an image from file using `cv::bridge` and publishes it.

Note that the example uses the older, C-style OpenCV API. If you're interested in using the newer C++ API, but don't know how, comment here and I'll try to put together a code snippet.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROS_NOOB_CYBORG](https://answers.ros.org/users/3275/ros_noob_cyborg/) on 2013-01-03**:
Ok man, thanks for the link! :) I try mine using python btw